# Order git diff --name-only list by commit/merge date

Tags: git, history, git-diff

When we use

`git diff --name-only <first tag>..<second tag>`

we've got the list of changed files but by alphabetical order.

What I want is the same list but by commit/merge history order, with older at top and the newest on the bottom.

Is there a native way with a git command/option to do this ?

Best regards,

Comment: `git diff` compares two points in the history, it does not access the history in between (by design). You would have to use `git log` instead but I don’t think there’s a built-in functionality to aggregate the file stats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git log`'s `format` option to print nothing about the commit, leaving the file name as the only thing printed:

```bash
git log --format="" --name-only <first tag>..<second tag>
```

As noted in the comments, `git log` has a `--reverse` option to list commits from the oldest to the newest:

```bash
git log --reverse --format="" --name-only <first tag>..<second tag>
```

You can also sort out duplicates using `awk` such that only the latest occurrence (or earliest if using `--reverse`)  is printed

```bash
git log --format="" --name-only <first tag>..<second tag> | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want but in the reverse sort. A way to have nearly what I want is to suffix your command with `| tac`

Comment: @saillantist missed the order part, mea culpa. `git log` has a `--reverse` option - check it out.

Comment: Thank you. I took the liberty of adding how to remove duplicates